# Rebar generated start up script not loading dependencies

Tags: erlang, riak, rebar

I'm very new to Erlang and using Rebar but we are doing a project that needs to connect to a Riak server, for this I'm trying to use the Riak Erlang client (`riakc_pb_socket` etc).

The problem is that the shell that is started from my start up script (generated by Rebar and reltool) does not include the dependencies I've specefied in my rebar.config (they download just fine when I do rebar get-deps however). I know that I can include them to my path when I start the shell myself (erl -pa PATH) but since this needs to be done automatically I wonder how I achive that, can I specify such behavior with Rebar or do I need to do code loading from inside the application?

Comment: This tutorial should reply to all of your questions: http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html

Comment: Thanks for that link, while it did help me understand my second question is does not answer how I can make reltool include the apps in my deps folder, any suggestions? I will edit my first post to reflect the new state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by Roberto Aloi I was able to figure out how the reltool works and after some working I found that all I had to do was add this line

```
{app, riakc, [{mod_cond, app}, {incl_cond, include}]},
```

To my reltool.config and now it works, so thanks a lot :)